# What is the difference between date transfer object (DTO) and representation object of domain driven design pattern?

Tags: domain-driven-design, dto

I know DTO is returned by the server-side and received by the client-side, but I am confused by the representation object in DDD. I think they are almost the same. Can someone tell me their differences?

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone tell me their differences?

They solve different problems in different contexts

Data transfer is a boundary concern - how do we move information from here to there (across a remote interface)?  Among the issues that you may run into: the transfer of information is slow, or expensive.  One way of keeping this under control is to move information in a larger grain.

> the main reason for using a Data Transfer Object is to batch up what would be multiple remote calls into a single call -- Martin Fowler, [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)

In other words, a DTO is your programs representation of a fat message.

In DDD, the value object pattern is a modeling concern; it is used to couple immutable representations of information and related computations.

---

A DTO tends to look like a data structure, with methods that can be used to transform that data structure into a representation (for example: an array of bytes) that can be sent across a boundary.

A value object tends to look like a data structure, with methods that can be used to compute other information that is likely to be interesting in your domain.

---

DTO tend to be more stable (or at least backwards compatible) out of necessity -- because producer and consumer are remote from one another, coordinating a change to both requires more effort than a single local change.

Value objects, in contrast, are easier to change because they are a domain model concern.  IF you want to change the model, that's just one thing, and correspondingly easier to coordinate.

(There's kind of a hedge - for system that need persistence, we need some way to get the information out of the object into a representation that can be stored and retrieved.  That's not necessarily a value object concern, especially if you are willing to use general purpose data structures to move information in and out of "the model".)

---

In the kingdom of nouns, the lines can get blurry - partly because any information that isn't a general purpose data structure/primitive is "an object", and partly because you can often get away with using the same objects for your internal concerns and boundary cnocerns.